# How to print the value of a specific column from java text file rather than it outputting null?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, text-files, multiple-columns

This is what I've got so far. It outputs null rather than the value from the text file. Also, it doesn't print out a specific column that I need and I'm trying to print out two columns at a time. I'm attempting to print the columns that contains the country names so that it would input the specific column rather than null. And if this doesn't work, is there a possibly easier way to get it done by splits?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Test { 
    
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String[][] data = readFile("network");
            int index = 2;
            String[] column = getSpecificColumn(data, index);
            for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(column[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    
    //creates a method that opens the file 
    public static String[][] readFile (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File text = new File(fileName);
        int numLines= 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (text);
        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(data);
            ++numLines;
        }
        reader.close();
    

        String[][] columns = new String[numLines][];
        int index = 0;
        reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            columns[index++] = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
        }
        reader.close();
        return columns;
    }
    public static String[] getSpecificColumn(String[][] data, int columnIndex) {
        String[] result = new String[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (columnIndex >= 0 && columnIndex < data[i].length) {
                result[i] = data[i][columnIndex];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Input file:

```
1   China   Japan   2   2   
2   Korea   India   2   2   
3   Korea   India   1   2   
4   Korea   Germany 1   2   
5   Japan   Germany 5   8   
6   India   Japan   5   8   
7   India   Japan   8   10  
8   China   Korea   6   9
```

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: I just edited it.